# Testing a repository with MSTest and Moq - .Verify not working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, moq, mstest

I am currently looking at writing unit tests for a basic execution timer with Moq. There is a function called when the timer is stopped which adds all timings into the database and I need to test that the insert has been called.
 I have used a similar kind of test to test inserts via the homecontroller but this is being done directly.

```
// Calls AddToLog() which iterates through the list 
// adding all entries to the database

_timer.Stop(); 
_repository.Verify(x => x.Insert(TimerObject));
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.Insert(.splitTimer)

Performed invocations:
ITimersRepository.Insert(EF.Domain.Entities.Timer)
ITimersRepository.Insert(EF.Domain.Entities.TimerSplit)
ITimersRepository.Save()
```

the addToLog() method is defiantly being called and is calling the .insert for the repository. I'm not really sure why it comes back as not being called?

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I belive I have the answer. It should be _timerRepository.Verify(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<Timer>()));. Could anyone verify I am doing it the correct way?

Comment: You might need to provide a little bit more context. Yes. You can verify with It.IsAny<Timer> like you say but also use explicit object if you configure it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought. Finding it a little difficult to see how I could pass it an explicit object as the objects are created within my executiontimer class not by passing in a new object. Any advice on how I might aproach passing in an object? i.e Stop() creates one entry into Timers and iterates through a list of all timer splits creating new entries for each within TimerSplits.

Comment: You can match it with It.Is<Timer>(t => condition), as you might know the values for the fields in Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_timerRepository.Verify(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<Timer>()));
```

This does the trick for what I needed. It checks to see if an insert has been triggered with a type of Timer and is not specific (Since it cant be as the object is created else where)